# editing dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

One of the columns in my R data frame looks like this:

```r
[1] "SVLEN=1007"   "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=204"    "SVLEN=-379"  
 [7] "SVLEN=-492"   "SVLEN=-825"   "SVLEN=-713"   "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=3553"   "SVLEN=432391"
[13] "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=-52"    "SVLEN=>1615"  "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=6899"   "SVLEN=."     
[19] "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=4468"   "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=627"   
[25] "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=1171"   "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=625"   
[31] "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=-237"   "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=-30"   
[37] "SVLEN=39"     "SVLEN=."      "SVLEN=-30"    "SVLEN=-377"   "SVLEN=120497" "SVLEN=."
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
[1] "1007"   "."      "."      "."      "204"    "-379"  
 [7] "-492"   "-825"   "-713"   "."      "3553"   "432391"
[13] "."      "-52"    ">1615"  "."      "6899"   "."     
[19] "."      "4468"   "."      "."      "."      "627"   
[25] "."      "."      "."      "1171"   "."      "625"   
[31] "."      "."      "-237"   "."      "."      "-30"   
[37] "39"     "."      "-30"    "-377"   "120497" "."
```

I could go in to the excel file I got it from and edit it but is there an easy way to do this in R?

**ANSWER**:

I found a solution to this probelm going back to the R documentation (https://www.statology.org/gsub-r/) use `gsub` to section off characters in a string. My command for this was: `gsub(".*=","\\1",df$SVLEN_INFO)`

And that worked!

Comment: Instead of adding that extra section to the question, can you please create an answer and put it there? It'll help the StackExchange algorithms to do the right things.

Comment: Can you check the `\\1`? I'm not an R expert but you need brackets for `\\1` to work, otherwise just use `''` as the replace term not with brackets. Thus it should be `gsub(".*=(.*)","\\1",df$SVLEN_INFO)`. Alternatively `gsub(".*=(-?\d+)","\\1",df$SVLEN_INFO)` might work better, not sure. I don't know how type casting works in R. @RamRS has a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an answer for now:

You can use `sub` to remove the `SVLEN=` part. You don't need `gsub` and you don't need regular expressions, let alone capture groups.

```r
df$SVLEN_INFO <- sub(x = df$SVLEN_INFO, pattern = "SVLEN=", replacement = "")
```

Comment: This is a good answer @rimo

Comment: this worked great! thank you

Answer (score -1):

Following gringer's advice I am also adding this solution:

Used gsub to section off characters in a string.

My command for this was: `gsub(".*=","\\1",df$SVLEN_INFO)`

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Does this work? You're using a backreference (`\1`) without a capture group (like `(.*)`), which usually does not work. Also, please use code formatting to format your post properly, I've done it for you this time.

Comment: I checked, this only works because `"\\1"` is empty since you don't have a capture group. Just use `""` instead of `"\\1"`. Otherwise, this is NOT a good solution as you're essentially using a bug.

Comment: worked for me at the time but again the answer above worked as well...so I'll use that to format moving forward...

Comment: Worked for you because it's a bug. If they fix the bug, it will stop working. Many reg-ex based tools error out or behave differently if you use backreferences without capture groups. IIRC `sed` retains the whole matched expression as the default backreference. Use predictable tools predictably instead of depending on bugs to hack your way through problems.